# Rake db:setup or rake db:create applying wrong username/wrong database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rake

Using Mac OSX Yosemite (10.10.4):

`rails -v => Rails 4.2.3`

`ruby -v => ruby 2.2.2p95`

Followed a combination of these instructions:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-ruby-on-rails-with-postgres
and these instructions:
http://blog.endpoint.com/2014/03/setup-rails-environment-with-postgresql.html

`bash:`

```
$createuser -P -d -e project (This was successful)
$password: aPassword
$re-enter password: aPassword
$rails new project --database=postgresql
$cd project/config/database.yml
```

Here is the config/database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode

  username: bespoke
  password: <%= ENV['PROJECT_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  #if I type env in bash => PROJECT_DATABASE_PROJECT: aPassword
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: Project_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: Project_test
```

So far so good... but then:

`rake db:create` The first time:
`myusername already exists`
Second time: `rake db:setup` I believe they're supposed to be the same things...

```
myusername already exists
Project_test already exists

/Users/myusername/Challenges/Project/db/schema.rb doesn't exist yet. Run `rake db:migrate` to create it, then try again. If you do not intend to use a database, you should instead alter /Users/myusername/Challenges/Project/config/application.rb to limit the frameworks that will be loaded.
```

So in other words the problem is: `rake db:create` or `rake db:setup` which seem to do the same exact were able to create the table `Project_test` hence they say `Project_test` already created... but they refused to create the table `Project_development` and instead insist on having me use the table `myusername` which is not listed anyWHERE~!

I have tried removing the default and hardcoding it into development to no avail. By the way here is output of `psql`=> `/list`

```
                                 List of databases
     Name     |  Owner  | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | Access privileges 
--------------+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------
 Project_test | project | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 postgres     | mee     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 myusername   | mee     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
```

Which proves that it did create the test database and used the correct Owner/user but it refused to create the development database.

What am I doing wrong or should I ask their github issues?

Comment: By the way it actually just says my particular user name which is a database name that I have used for other stuff (so its not creating that database at all) it's just deciding to default to that database... which was uncalled for I have tried redoing project many times. Including after a reboot/refresh of env by closing bash

Comment: I've exactly the same problem.  It only became apparent when I started work on a second application as the database/first application worked fine being called <username> rather than <appname>_development.
If it helps, I'm on; Rails 4.2.4 & ruby 2.2.2p95 & OS X 11.2 El Capitan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved! It was an environment variable. First, I used env to see all the variables and noticed a DATABASE_URL was set.

```
$env
...
DATABASE_URL=postgres:///steve
...
```

So I thought, maybe the environment variable is taking precedent over `<appname>_development` (but not applied when generating `<appname>_test`)
Then, I looked at my .zshrc file and saw where this value was being set:

```
➜  ~  cat .zshrc
# Added by Steve for permanent path vars
 export DATABASE_URL=postgres:///$(whoami)
```

Once I commented out this export line, then reloaded/restarted shell, running `rake db:create` generates `<appname>_development` as it should.

I don't remember why I needed to set that default but I'm glad I made a note in the config file, perhaps following a guide for using postgres client via the command line.
Hope that helps someone else

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. It's a little creepy that I also had a DATABASE_URL environment variable in my zsrhc. I did a bit of digging and it seems to be coming from some [Heroku rails / postgres setup instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup).