# Console DB commands using other apps database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For the life of me, I cannot figure out what the heck is going on.

Rails 5.1.6 on OSx Mojave.

I have multiple rails apps on my local machine so I use puma-dev to run them all at their testing URLs.

For whatever reason whenever I attempt to create the database for the new app it is using the database.yml config of the other app.

So RPGBeacon is the new app and Gamers Paradise is the old app, completely independent projects.

When I attempt to run `bin/rails db:create` from the rpgbeacon directory I get the message Database 'gameswap_dev' already exists.

I have no idea why the rails command is using the other database when rpgbeacon has it's own database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: rpgbeacon_dev
  pool: 50
```

I'm not sure what else to try. I've tried killing puma-dev, rebooting, begging not sure what else to do.

I saw a stackoverflow post somewhere else that mentioned stopping spring, I tried that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. It was due to some global ENV variables set in .zshrc. Apparently, I forgot to undo them when I was cli debugging the other app for puma-dev. 
Got rid of

```
export DATABASE_URL=postgresql://localhost:5432/gameswap_dev
```

and now everything works just fine.

Got the inspiration from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31595245/rake-dbsetup-or-rake-dbcreate-applying-wrong-username-wrong-database)
in case the link goes away:

> Solved! It was an environment variable. First, I used env to see all the variables and noticed a DATABASE_URL was set.